# How do i create a new file in the current working directory for an atom package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, atom-editor

I'm trying to make an atom package with JavaScript that will create a new file in the current working directory and add some text to the file. How would I go about that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you read tutorials on creating atom packages such as: https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-write-a-syntax-highlighting-package-for-atom/

Comment: The tutorial you have given is for syntax packages? I'm not sure what to try. cant find anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I looked through some other atom packages and found out they use a module called `fs` and to get the current working directory they use `atom.project.getPaths()[0]` so I got it to work!

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile(atom.project.getPaths()[0] + '\\test.txt', "Hey there!", function(err) {
  if(err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  console.log("The file was saved!");
});
```